# Swing закрытие окна

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать простое приложение на java swing. 

Мне нужно чтобы было Первое окно, по нажатию на кнопку должно открываться второе окно, а первое должно быть закрыто.

Текущий код такой:

```
    public class SimpleGUI extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public SimpleGUI(){
        super("Example");
        frame.setBounds(100,100,250,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,2,2));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        container.add(label);
        JButton button = new JButton("YES");
        container.add(button);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("NO");
        container.add(button2);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                frame2.setBounds(100,100,250,100);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

вроде бы `frame.setVisible(false);` должен закрыть первое окно, но ничего не происходит.

Вот код из метода **main**

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUI app = new SimpleGUI();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Дык вы ж сначала откройте первое окно. А то закрываете то, чего не видно

Comment: Оно открывается первое окно, с кнопками, после нажатия на кнопку открывается второе окно, но первое не закрывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем не понятно, зачем вы в основном окне создаете поле типа `Frame` и ему присваеваете параметры, а потом вызываете на нем `setVisible(false)`, он же и так не отображается. Предлагаю его убрать, тогда ваш код с небольшими изменениями станет рабочим.

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

  public MyWindow() {
    setTitle("first frame");
    setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    container.add(label);
    JButton button = new JButton("YES");
    container.add(button);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("NO");
    container.add(button2);
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        setVisible(false);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("second frame")
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
    myWindow.setVisible(true);
  }}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!